# iOS - Access App created Files and Folders

Tags: android, ios, file, file-management

I am currently developing a Text Editor for coding for Android, and I am interested in creating an iPhone and iPad Version as well. I heard that iOS does not have a File Management system, and you cannot normally access files through a PC. Would it be possible for my app to create a folder and file (say, a Java or Swift file), and then display the names of those files in the main screen and allow the app to open that file that it created?

Tl;dr: Can I make files, and access them in the app?

Android Code for reference: https://github.com/MJonesDev/Pocket-Editor-Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

To create java file:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *stringToWrite = @"1\n2\n3\n4";
NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.java"];
[stringToWrite writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

To read java file:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Source from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112572/how-to-create-a-txt-file-programmatically-on-ios)